# creating function repeat character

Tags: c, loops, char, printf, scanf

Write a program that prompts the user to enter in a character and an integer. Implement a function called `repeat_character()` that takes the two arguments (character and an integer) entered by the user and displays the character by duplicating it the integer number of times on the screen with a single space between the characters.   For example:

> Enter a character and a number: A 7
>
> A A A A A A A

This is my code:

```
int num;
char c;

void repeat_character(char,int);
int main() {
     printf("Enter character and how many times repeated\n");
     scanf("%s%d",&c,&num);

    repeat_character(c,num);
    return 0;

}  

 void repeat_character(char c, int num) 
{
     if (num>=1)
     printf("%s*%d", &c);
     else
         printf(0);
 
 }
```

It is printing:

> enter character and how many times repeated
>
> a 4
>
> ap ?U? * 13283362

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `printf("%s*%d", &c);` <-- you have two specifiers in the string but only one value supplied. This is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Point 1:** You need to change your code

```
scanf("%s%d",&c,&num);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c%d",&c,&num);
```

in your code `c` is a `char`, and the correct format specifier for a `char` is `%c`, not `%s`.

**Point 2:** you've to use a [**loop**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow#Loops) in `repeat_character()` to. The *format string*, supplied to `printf()` is not *evaluated*, as you might have expected. You need to do something like

```
void repeat_character(char c, int num) 
{
     int counter = 0;
     for (counter = 0; counter < num; counter ++)
         printf("%c ", c);     //notice the change in format specifier
 }
```

Note: I suggest, you read the manual pages for [`printf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) and [`scanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) before performing any other operation to know the correct sysntax of those functions.

Comment: @CoolGuy Thanks. Added a whole `\t` itself. :-)

Comment: The `\t` is probably not what OP was after: "A A A A "

Comment: @Jongware Extremely sorry. Somehow missed that part. Updated accordingly. Thanks for pointing that out and allowing to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very basic misunderstanding:

The statement

```
printf("%s*%d", ...);
```

will print **two** arguments, separated by a `*`character: `A*7` it will **not** print the character 7 times.

If you want print a character several times, use a loop:

```
while(num--) printf("%c ", c);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int num;
char c;

void repeat_character(char, int);

int main() {
printf("Enter character and how many times repeated\n");
scanf("%c%d", &c, &num);        //getting inputs corresponding

repeat_character(c, num);       //calling function and sending parameters
getch();
return 0;

}

void repeat_character(char c, int num)     //receiving parameters
{
if (num >= 1){              //checking if number is greater than zero
    int i = num;            //initializing i with num
    while (i != 0){         //loop will continue till it value becomes zero
        printf("%c", c);    //printing char single time in each iteration 
        i--;                //decrementing the value of i
    }
}
else
    printf(0);
}
```

Comment: Please fix your formattimng, `"%c"`-> `"%c "` (separate chars by a single space), your `while()` should be a `for()` or better replaced by `while(num--)`